# Spring @Cacheable annotation not working with caffeine cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, caffeine-cache

I'm trying to get @Cacheable annotation working on one of my cache service class.
Cache manager class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CaffeineCacheManager extends CachingConfigurerSupport{
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(){
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeinieCacheManager("appConfigCache","sysConfigCache");
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(
            Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .initialCapacity(300)
                .maximumSize(1000)
                .recordStats()
            );
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

I have two cache service class

```java
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheName={"appConfigCache"})
public class AppConfigurationCacheService{
    @Autowired
    private AppConfigurationDao appConfigurationDao;
    
    @Cacheable(key="#appConfigKey")
    public AppConfiguration getAppConfig(String appConfigKey){
        AppConfiguration appConfig = appConfigurationDao.getAppConfigurationByKey(appConfigKey);
        return appConfig;
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheName={"sysConfigCache"})
public class SysConfigurationCacheService{
    @Autowired
    private SysConfigurationDao sysConfigurationDao;
    
    @Cacheable(key="#configKey")
    public SysConfiguration getSysConfig(String configKey){
        
        SysConfiguration sysConfig = sysConfigurationDao.getSysConfigurationByKey(configKey);
        return sysConfig;
    }
}
```

When I execute `loadApplicationConfig` from the following class it will always retrieve it from the database using `AppConfigurationDao` class

```java
@Service
public class LoadApplicationConfig{
    
    @Autowired
    private AppConfigurationCacheService appCacheService;
    
    public void loadApplicationConfig(String configName){
        //This method does not retrieve object from cache but from the database
        AppConfiguration appConfig = appCacheService.getAppConfig(configName);
    }
}
```

`@Cacheable` works on `SysConfigurationCacheService` class. It will retrieve the object from the cache. Also in `SysConfigurationCacheService` if I put different SpEL like `key"#configKey"` it will throw an exception. However, in `AppConfigurationCacheService` it does not throw any exception. I've been looking at this for couple of days and I can't figure out why caffeine cache is not working on `AppConfigurationCacheService` class. I desperately need some insight on this issue. 
 Thank you in advance